# How to make thumbnail size be in effect in XnView?

Tags: xnview

I have set thumbnail size to 384x288 in XnView. This caused image places to enlarge, but not thumbnails themselves were not enlarged:

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

This way did have result for me:

1. Set checkbox "Tools => options => thumbnails => Create thumbnail from original if embedded is smaller than thumbnail size"
2. Go to "View => rebuild thumbnails".

XnView allows to use custom thumbnails size: in that menu "Tools => options => thumbnails => appearance". I found best size 455x350 for fullHD monitor.

On my 64-bit system, XnView stores thumbnail cache in AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\XnView folder.